# How to do this: obj[i].["name of thing in object"]

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json

I tried to work it out and ask who I could but no one gave me an answer that would work. can anyone advise me?

```js
obj[i].["name of thing in object"]
```

this is array:

```json
[
 {
  "name": "DISBOARD#2760",
  "id": "3020508723832240"
 },
 {
  "name": "Gumernus#0122",
  "id": "7814540349956106"
 }
]
```

Comment: May you share the object too? Also `[i].["name ...` is a syntax error.

Comment: Could you please provide more informations? what is the variable object filled with? What do you need to retrieve?

Comment: what about something like `obj.find(item => item.name === "DISBOARD#2760")` ?

Comment: I will adjust it so that you can see the whole array

Comment: evolutionxbox but I need item.name to be item.id etc.. i want to change anything i want

Comment: That's what functions are for. `myFunction = (prop, value) => obj.find(item => item[prop] === value)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your object looks a bit like

```js
let obj = [
  { nameOfThingInObject: 'first'},
  { nameOfThingInObject: 'second'}
];
```

To retrieve the `nameOfThingInObject` you can do two things:

1. Use `.` to access the property
2. Use `[]` to access the property

Your example in the question seems to try both, which will result in an error. To retrieve the value, you can thus do:

```js
let firstMethod = obj[0].nameOfThingInObject;
let secondMethod = obj[0]['nameOfThingInObject'];
```

Comment: Let me know if this is what you're looking for. If it isn't, I'm happy to change my solution

Comment: yes i needed the second method really thanks